# How to return an original ImageView resource?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView defined in layout file like:

```
  android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
```

During my application workflow I change the resource several times using

```
  iv.setImageResource(some_id);
```

However if something going wrong I want to get my original resource back. Here is no method like `ImageView.resetToDefault()` and I do not see any other way than preserve original resource id in my program and set it when I need to return image back. However I need each time modify my code if I decided to change the resource attached to image view. So if somebody knows more elegant solution, then let me know.

PS I can see similar questions unanswered, so it seems Android design lack.

Guys, what about such work around? I make two image views stackable. So my image on top is invisible by XML definition. When I need update image, I just make it visible and reload image. When I want to get image default, I just hide it. Let me try.

Comment: Just call **iv.setImageResource(some_id);** once again.

Comment: @Artoo I value your sense of humor, but how to solve my problem? Any clue?

Comment: You see? your accepted answer simply copied from my comment... So, I already answered (without humor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the view is inflated or set, set the ImageView resource programmatically.

```
defaultImageId = R.drawable.ic_home;
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.layout.my_image_view);
iv.setImageResource(defaultImageId);

//.... sometime later when you want to reset back to the "default"
iv.setImageResource(defaultImageId);
```

EDIT:

If you insist on keeping the resource id in XML only, ImageView does not allow for this to in its current state.  You'll have to extend it and provide the functionality yourself.  See the gist below for a working example.  (I have tested it).

https://gist.github.com/enragedmrt/9143603

Comment: I am asking how I can figure out resource id which was defined in XML, the solution you given already stated in my question.

Comment: Why keep it defined in XML and not in code?  Is there any advantage/reasoning?  You say you'd have to modify your code if you update the resource id, but you'd have to the same in XML anyways.  What difference does it make if you move android:src="@drawable/some_id" to code using R.drawable.some_id?

Comment: Yes, XML is presentation layer and generally view in MVC. It is simple design rule do not spread things related to one functionality in many places, otherwise you will have hard time to maintain your product.

Comment: Fair enough.  See my updated answer.  It adds a lot more bloat than is usually necessary though.

Comment: Do you want to keep copyright for your solution? I have an intent to add it in my library https://github.com/drogatkin/pertusin

Comment: No not at all.  But if you plan to use it and it works, accept the answer :).  Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although Enragedmrt provided a wonderful solution,  I still came with a work around as below:

```
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_orig"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_default" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_towork"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_default" />
```

So when I want set to default I just do `iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: If you're going to do this, just set a background and clear the ImageView resource whenever you want to show the "default".

Comment: You mean background for an image view? I can't set background for entire layout since I have several images behaving like that.